# sessionStorage between parent and child pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have an HTML5 page where I store some data with:

```
 window.sessionStorage.setItem('toStore', 'hello world');
```

Then, I open from this window a pop-up one with:

```
 window.open('mobile.html', 'myPopUp');
```

I have a set of Javascript functions associated to the two pages, where I want to access the local storage data of parent page from the popUp with the `getItem('toStore')` call.
Is that possible? If yes, what's the calling syntax?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? It would probably be window.opener.sessionStorage.

Comment: @BNL. Sorry, I don't understand ...

Comment: @BNL. It was not clear, now is done: as you say, from the child it should be called like this: window.opener.sessionStorage.setItem('toStore', 'hello world'). Thanks!

Comment: @user238831 Accept some answers on your previous questions and people might be more willing to help you understand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

```
window.opener.sessionStorage.setItem('toStore', 'hello world');
```